How to use recursive SQL to find the parent ID
I'm a noob in the recursive domain in that I understand the syntax but I'm unable to apply it to my current problem. I'm using Postgre SQL.
I have a product_id 'ABC123' that has a parent category 'FG_ACC_CA', which itself has parent category 'FG_ACC', which also has a parent category 'FG'. The 'FG' does not have a parent category.
I'm trying to use recursive query to find the top most parent of the given product_id.
Here parent_id & product_id are columns and product_category & product_product are their respective tables.
The syntax that I'm trying to use is this
enter image description here
Here's the query I've written:
with recursive ancestor as 
(
    select pc.parent_id as temp
    from product_product pp 
    left join product_category pc on pc.id = pp.categ_id
    where pp.product_id = 'ABC123'

    union

    select temp
    from ancestor a
    where a.temp != Null
)
select *
from ancestor
;

The results I get is just the parent_id of ABC123. So I guess I'm butchering the recursive part after union.
Also while researching I've come across multiple parent-child examples but they all use 'inner join' instead of 'where' even though they explain the concept with 'where' as a recursive condition. Couldn't figure out why.

No images, please; hard to read and copy. Could you please add some content to the test?

In the recursive clause, the recursive table (product_category) must be included in the query and joined with the results of the recursion (ancestor).
with recursive ancestor as (
    select pc.parent_id as temp
    from product_product pp
    left join product_category pc on pc.id = pp.categ_id
    where pp.product_id = 'ABC123'

    union all

    select pc.parent_id as temp
    from product_category pc
    inner join ancestor a on a.temp = pc.id
    where a.temp is not null
)
select temp from ancestor;


Thanks null, that worked!! I got all the categories in the hierarchy. It still works even if I remove the 'where' clause as now it's redundant I guess. I have one query regarding your process: can we achieve recursion in this case by just using the 'where' clause? why do we need the inner join? I was trying to follow this syntax.

@user27975638 The second select is really used for recursion, which joins the table that needs to be recursive with the recursive temporary table, that is, all the previous results are joined with the required table to query the data that is satisfied in the next round. For example, in the first round of recursion, A, B, and C are put into a temporary table, and in the next round of recursion, you need to use the temporary table to join and find the related data of A, B, and C. Where is often used as a filter or recursive terminating condition, so just using a where clause is not enough

Without some sample data it is hard to offer an answer.
If your data looks something like this:
product_category table



id
parent_id
category




1
1
FG


2
1
FG_ACC


3
2
FG_ACC_CA


4
4
GG


5
4
GG_BDD



product_product table



id
product
category_id




11
ABC123
3


12
DEF456
5



... no need for recursion - you could use self joins to get the root category of your products ...
WITH
  ancestors AS
    ( Select    pc_0.id, pc_0.parent_id as root_id, 
                pc_0.parent_id, pc_0.category, 
                pc_1.id as child_id,
                pp.product, pp.id as product_id
      From      product_category pc_0
      Left Join product_category pc_1 ON( pc_1.parent_id = pc_0.id )
      Left Join product_product pp ON( pp.category_id = pc_1.id )
      Where     pc_0.parent_id IN( Select id From product_category Where id = parent_id ) And
                pp.id Is Not Null 
  ) 
Select  DISTINCT 
            a.product_id, a.product, a.root_id, pc.category as root_category
From        ancestors a
Inner Join  product_category pc ON( pc.id = a.root_id )
Order By    a.product_id

R e s u l t :



product_id
product
root_id
root_category




11
ABC123
1
FG


12
DEF456
4
GG



... if your product could be deeper in hierarchy ( added root 0 ) ...
product_category table   ( added id 0 )



id
parent_id
category




0
0
F


1
0
FG


2
1
FG_ACC


3
2
FG_ACC_CA


4
4
GG


5
4
GG_BDD



... you will need to add another selfjoin ( pc_2 ) and adjust ON conditions for pp table ...
WITH
  ancestors AS
    ( Select    pc_0.id, pc_0.parent_id as root_id, 
                pc_0.parent_id, pc_0.category, 
                pc_1.id as child_id, pc_2.id as grandchild_id,
                pp.product, pp.id as product_id
      From      product_category pc_0
      Left Join product_category pc_1 ON( pc_1.parent_id = pc_0.id )
      Left Join product_category pc_2 ON( pc_2.parent_id = pc_1.id )
      Left Join product_product pp ON( pp.category_id IN( pc_1.id, pc_2.id ) )
      Where     pc_0.parent_id IN( Select id From product_category Where id = parent_id ) And
                pp.id Is Not Null 
  ) 
Select  DISTINCT 
            a.product_id, a.product, a.root_id, pc.category as root_category
From        ancestors a
Inner Join  product_category pc ON( pc.id = a.root_id )
Order By    a.product_id

R e s u l t :



product_id
product
root_id
root_category




11
ABC123
0
F


12
DEF456
4
GG



fiddle
UPDATE (after comment)
Here's the code adjusted to the context described in the comment (parent is null for root id and tiers 0,1,2,3)...
Coalesce() function puts id value wheere parent id is null, added Left Joins to the cte in order to cover 4 tiers ...
--      S a m p l e    D a t a : 
Create Table product_category (id Int, parent_id Int, category Varchar(12));
Insert Into product_category VALUES
  ( 0, Null, 'F' ),
  ( 1, 0, 'FG' ),
  ( 2, 1, 'FG_ACC' ),
  ( 3, 2, 'FG_ACC_CA' ), 
  ( 4, 3, 'FG_ACC_CA_C' ), 
  ( 5, Null, 'GG' ), 
  ( 6, 5, 'GG_BDD' );

Create Table product_product (id Int, product Varchar(12), category_id Int);
Insert Into product_product VALUES
  ( 11, 'ABC123', 4 ),
  ( 12, 'DEF456', 6);

Select * From product_category;
Select * From product_product;




id
parent_id
category




0
null
F


1
0
FG


2
1
FG_ACC


3
2
FG_ACC_CA


4
3
FG_ACC_CA_C


5
null
GG


6
5
GG_BDD






id
product
category_id




11
ABC123
4


12
DEF456
6



WITH         -- changed cte ancestors to context from the comment
  ancestors AS
    ( Select    pc_0.id, Coalesce(pc_0.parent_id, pc_0.id) as root_id, 
                Coalesce(pc_0.parent_id, pc_0.id) as parent_id, pc_0.category, 
                pc_1.id as child_id, pc_2.id as grandchild_id,
                pp.product, pp.id as product_id
      From      product_category pc_0
      Left Join product_category pc_1 ON( pc_1.parent_id = pc_0.id )
      Left Join product_category pc_2 ON( pc_2.parent_id = pc_1.id )
      Left Join product_category pc_3 ON( pc_3.parent_id = pc_2.id )
      Left Join product_product pp ON( pp.category_id IN( pc_1.id, pc_2.id, pc_3.id ) )
      Where     Coalesce(pc_0.parent_id, pc_0.id) IN( Select id From product_category Where parent_id Is Null) And
                pp.id Is Not Null 
  ) 
--      M a i n    S Q L : 
Select      a.product_id, a.product, a.root_id, pc.category as root_category
From        ancestors a
Inner Join  product_category pc ON( pc.id = a.root_id )
Order By    a.product_id

R e s u l t :



product_id
product
root_id
root_category




11
ABC123
0
F


12
DEF456
5
GG



fiddle

Thanks for the feedback and the detailed explanation, d r.
The table you created is fairly accurate to mine. The only difference is that the parent_id of the root category is not the same as the id but is NULL. I tried to make some changes in the fiddle link you shared and was able to make it work for FG but not GG. fiddle_1. In my database the product categories could be 0,1,2, or 3 tiers.

@user27975638 Just posted an update that should cover all tyers and handles Nulls in parent id... https://dbfiddle.uk/MIU5qz0M
